# referential integrity enforcement trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, referential-integrity

I need to code a referential integrity trigger on the department (dept_no) table and the employee table. The trigger should fire if records in the department table are being updated or deleted. If it is necessary to rollback the transaction it will print 'Transaction failed' otherwise it should print 'Transaction succeeded'.

But I'm not really sure where to even start.
Here are the columns for the department table:

[image]

and here are the columns for the employee table:

[image]

How do I achieve this sort of thing?

Comment: My bad, fixing it now.

Comment: gyazo is a screenshot kinda thing @Siyual ... safe this time, but does look dubious.

Comment: All fixed up. I used stackoverflow's image embedding

Comment: So since dept_no is an fk, you shouldn't be able to delete departments if the department is used in the employee table unless it is written with `on delete cascade` more about foreign keys: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx

Comment: If you are looking to write triggers to prevent departments from being updated you can write `instead of update` and `instead of delete` triggers. more about that here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx